# How do I convert a 2 byte C date into .NET DateTime using C#?

Tags: c#, c, date, datetime

I am having trouble reading/writing a binary file containing date information. The struct covering the relevant portion of the file is:

```
typedef struct {
    short int  blah1;       
    short int  blah2;        
    short int  blah3;        
    short int  blah4;  
    short int  blah5;   
    WORD       date_created;   /* Creation date, packed as in a directory */
    time_t     time;           /* Creation time, from bios interrupt 1Ah */
    etc
```

From this I believe that 2 bytes (WORD) are being used to store the date and 4 bytes to store the time_t.

I have a sample file that should contain the date 01/08/2001 (dd/mm/yyyy). The 2 byte values I read from the *date_created* portion of the file are decimal 0x0D and 0x2B.

In case I have extracted the incorrect values, the file's first 80 bytes are [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25102974/20010801%20Fragment.bin) and dump as follows

```
od -t x1 "20010801 Fragment.bin"     
0000000 01 00 1c 01 00 00 bc 02 00 00 0d 2b 8b 00 77 3b
0000020 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
0000120
```

I have searched around but can't find anything that deals with storing date as a WORD. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting the problem and therefore not searching properly or not recognising the answers when I see them - sorry - not a C programmer.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

re: the time_t, I think I am converting it correctly using:

```
public static UInt32 To_time_t(DateTime toConvert)
{
    return (UInt32)(toConvert - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
}

public static DateTime From_time_t(UInt32 toConvert)
{
    DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return epoch.AddSeconds(toConvert);
}
```

...but please let me know if this is the wrong approach..

Comment: Your `time_t` conversion looks fine to me, but I don't see how that expected date is related to the actual bytes.

Comment: The MS-DOS date format is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724247(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Don't forget time zone and daylight savings.

Comment: Even having one more sample set of data and expected date would be very useful.

Comment: Note: `time_t t = 0x3b77008b;
  puts(asctime(gmtime(&t)));
` --> "Sun Aug 12 22:17:47 2001".  11 days off of "01/08/2001".  Hmmmm

Comment: The date `01/08/2001` is not in MS_DOS date format as `0x0D2B` nor `0x2B0D`.  `0x2B0D` in MS-DOS format is 2002 Aug 13th.  More hmmmm.

Comment: Is there maybe a legacy tool which can read that file format and which you could use? If yes, you could manipulate your sample file and inspect in the legacy tool what it will show (so doing a reverse engineering).

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the replies! Based on the link by Raymond Chen, I have implemented the code below as a starting point. It returns a date of 13/08/2001 which is very close to the expected date. Thanks Oliver, I found a contact with a legacy application and they confirmed the date to be 13/08/2001 (contradicting the assumption that files were named based on collection date).

Thanks again.

In case it helps someone else my code and unit test are:

```
    internal struct Systime
    {
        internal UInt16 Year;
        internal UInt16 Month;
        internal UInt16 DayOfWeek;
        internal UInt16 Day;
        internal UInt16 Hour;
        internal UInt16 Minute;
        internal UInt16 Second;
        internal UInt16 Milliseconds;
    }

    internal struct FileTime
    {
        internal UInt32 dwLowDateTime;
        internal UInt32 dwHighDateTime;
    }

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern bool DosDateTimeToFileTime(UInt16 wFatDate, UInt16 wFatTime, ref FileTime lpFileTime);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern bool FileTimeToSystemTime(ref FileTime lpFileTime, ref Systime lpSystemTime);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern bool FileTimeToDosDateTime(ref FileTime lpFileTime, ref UInt16 wFatDate, ref UInt16 wFatTime);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern bool SystemTimeToFileTime(ref Systime lpSystemTime, ref FileTime lpFileTime);


public static DateTime FromMSDosDate(UInt16 toConvert)
{
    FileTime fileTime = new FileTime();
    Systime systemTime = new Systime();

    DosDateTimeToFileTime(toConvert, 0, ref fileTime);
    FileTimeToSystemTime(ref fileTime, ref systemTime);

    return new DateTime(systemTime.Year, systemTime.Month, systemTime.Day, 0, 0, 0);
}

public static UInt16 ToMSDosDate(DateTime toConvert)
{
    Systime systemTime = new Systime();
    FileTime fileTime = new FileTime();
    UInt16 fatDate = 0;
    UInt16 fatTime = 0;

    systemTime.Day = (UInt16)toConvert.Day;
    systemTime.Month = (UInt16)toConvert.Month;
    systemTime.Year = (UInt16)toConvert.Year;

    SystemTimeToFileTime(ref systemTime, ref fileTime);
    FileTimeToDosDateTime(ref fileTime, ref fatDate, ref fatTime);

    return fatDate;
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test_MSDos_Date()
{
    UInt16 testDate = 11021; // int value read from binary test file...
    DateTime expected = new DateTime(2001, 8, 13, 0, 0, 0);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, Utils.FromMSDosDate(testDate));
    Assert.AreEqual(testDate, Utils.ToMSDosDate(expected));
}
```